# Run script at boot

Tags: autohotkey, boot, autorun

I have a script that I would like to run at system startup so that it's always available. I am lazy and don't want to run the script manually each time. How can I make the script run on startup?

Comment: SO is meant for programming questions. Your question is more suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/). I flagged it in order to be moved there.

Comment: Yes, and if you want this kind of help, you have to post some code to show what you have done so far.  Folks here will help you with the code, not write it for you.  Your question will likely get closed if you don't do this.

Answer (score 5):

To run script at startup:

1. Compile the script to .exe file using converter that is installed
   with AutoHotkey.
2. Put compiled .exe file or link to it to startup folder

Comment: Find the startup folder by typing "shell:startup" into the adress pane of explorer.